# TableView auto reorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a tableView on which I can add cells normally. Just so you understand, my tableView is populated by a core data on which I use fetch to get the items and add them to a mutable array, all the usual. After the fetch though, I call the reload method from tableview. But if I enter the cell to edit its content, when I get back to it, the tableview gets reordered automatically and I think that's because of the reload method, but if I don't call it, nothing shows up from the fetch. Here is my fetch:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity1"];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest2 = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Entity2"];
self.titles = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
self.stitles = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest2 error:nil]mutableCopy];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Also, it only reorders the second array, the one with the subtitles. There's surely a way to stop this from happening or to reload the tableView somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reuse your fetchedResultsController property. Inside the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate delegate method, use something like this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reload entire tableview actually. You can reload the specific cell like this:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedRow animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```